# Configure UWF via PowerShell DSC

Tags: windows-10, powershell, uwf

Is there any way to configure the Universal Write Filter of Windows 10 via a Powershell DSC (Desired State Configuration)? I.e. configure exclusions, enable/disable etc. I did not yet find any DSC resource for it.